# Is there a faster way to return a formatted string from a member function?

Tags: c++, string

I created a mathematical vector class, and because it could be called 60 times a second in real time, I'm concerned that this algorithm is too slow. It basically grabs (x,y) in vector format and returns the string. Is there a faster way to do the same thing?

I researched that placing 'static' before the buffer array is one way. I also don't like the binary copy of the returned string (or assumedly the copy constructor). It does need to return std::string.

```
std::string Vector2D::toString() const
{
    char buffer[20];

    snprintf(buffer, 20, "(%.02f, %.02f)", m_x, m_y); 

    return std::string(buffer, strlen(buffer));
}
```

Comment: Have you measured the time it takes to run this? I would bet that on any machine built within the past decade this will not take a significant amount of time, but benchmarking is the only way to test it

Comment: While measuring with GetTickCount(), I'm getting 0. Probably fast enough :)

Comment: Run it a million times to get an actual value. But in any case it will most certainly be fast enough

Comment: With a million times, 3031 ms with 'static char', 3063 ms with 'char'.

Comment: I assume that means it takes 0.003031% of a second to run once (3031/1000000)

Comment: Yes, you can run this about 300000 times per second on your system. Running it 60 times won’t be an issue

Comment: Well, I learned the importance of measuring. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the `std::string` won't get copied. It will get moved, where the internal pointer gets copied instead of the characters. This takes constant time.

Comment: @FeiXiang: Well, with small string optimization, it might be copying characters.  Just a small amount of them.

Comment: @FeiXiang Since C++11, I think (correct me if I wrong), the std::string is treated as an rvalue in the return statement. It will either be returned via Return-Value-Optimization (no copy, no move), or if the compiler decides it can not perform RVO, then it will use string's move constructor to do the return. Only if RVO is not performed, and if the returned type did not have a move constructor, would the copy constructor be used for the return.

Comment: "too slow" compared to what? If the string is being displayed somewhere, chances are that the time involved in creating the string is swamped by the time needed to render it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenters that performance is unlikely to be a measurable problem for you -- at least not on any modern computer -- but if you want to reduce overhead anyway, just an exercise, you can change the method to write into a caller-supplied char-array rather than returning a std::string:

```
void Vector2D::writeToCharBuffer(char * buffer) const
{
   snprintf(buffer, 20, "(%.02f, %.02f)", m_x, m_y); 
}
```

This avoids the call to `strlen()`, the need for copying the chars from `buffer` into a `std:string` object's internal array, and perhaps the need for the `std:string` to allocate (and later free) a buffer from the heap, thus increasing your program's efficiency by some negligible amount.

The downside is that it is harder for the caller to use correctly, e.g. instead of

```
std::string s = vec.toString();
```

he now has to do something like:

```
char tempBuf[20];
vec.writeToCharBuffer(tempBuf);
```

... and God help him if he forgets that the function needs a buffer of at least 20 bytes:

```
char tempBuf[10];               // oopsie
vec.writeToCharBuffer(tempBuf); // buffer overflow -> undefined behavior, chaos and despair!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `strlen` call, by using the return value from `snprintf`.

You can potentially save the copy into the `string` buffer, by preallocating the string to the buffer size, calling `snprintf` directly into the string's storage, and then resizing to the return value of `snprintf`.

You can do slightly better than that by calling some dedicated number formatting functions (along the lines of `itoa`, but not exactly `itoa`, because that doesn't do floating-point or accept a precision) to fill the buffer, instead of `snprintf` which has to process a control string.

None of this will matter if you call this function only a few thousand times.  You need to be calling it tens of millions of times in order for it to be a noticeable difference.